# Trouble selecting and clicking website button using Python 3.5.1 & Selenium 2.53.2

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm currently using a Macbook Air running OS X El Capitan. I'm using the Python IDLE and trying to select and click on the following webpage button:

```
<div class="search-form-actions">
  <button class="btn btn-submit js-search-form-submit" selector=".js-search-form-submit" helptip="When you are ready to view all the contacts that match your criteria, click View Results." data-placement="top" data-step-number="5" data-step-name="Get Results">View Results</button>
</div>
```

By using the following script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
type(browser)
browser.get('https://app.avention.com/')

#enter username
usernameElem = browser.find_element_by_name("username")
usernameElem.send_keys('myusername')
usernameElem.submit()

#enter password
usernameElem = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
usernameElem.send_keys('mypassword')
usernameElem.submit()

#selecting 'Saved Searches' page
htmlElem = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("html") #without this line, site blocks next command
browser.get('https://app.avention.com/search/saved/7a1fbf2d-329a-4fda-8c51-4be5bc07317c#')

#selecting 'View Results' button
resultsElem = browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn.btn-submit.js-search-form-submit").click()
```

I receive the following error:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"class
>   name","selector":"btn.btn-submit.js-search-form-submit"}

I have tried to find_element_by_class_name

I have tried to find_element_by_name

I have tried to find_element_by_id

I have tried to find_element_by_link_text

But with no success. Any suggestions. Many thanks.

Gavin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class_name` receives one class name

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn")
# or
browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn-submit")
# or
browser.find_element_by_class_name("js-search-form-submit")
```

If you want all the classes together use `css_selector`

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-submit.js-search-form-submit")
```

You also can't assign the results to variable and click on it in the same time. It should be

```
resultsElem = browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn")
# or
browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn").click()
```

Comment: Thank you Guy, that helped a lot, it turns out the button had a different class_name all together but your correction of separating the assignment and click function would have saved me further headache. cheers